# How to write a custom loss function in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to `tensorflow`. I want to write my own custom loss function. Is there any tutorial about this? For example, the hinge loss or a sum_of_square_loss(though this is already in tf)?
Can I do it directly in python or I have to write the cpp code?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

We need to write down the loss function. For example, we can use basic mean square error as our loss function for predicted y and target y_:

```
 loss_mse = 1/n(Sum((y-y_)^2))
```

There are basic functions for tensors like `tf.add(x,y)`, `tf.sub(x,y)`, `tf.square(x)`, `tf.reduce_sum(x)`, [etc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math).

Then we can define our loss function in Tensorflow like:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(y,y_)))
```

Note: y and y_ are tensors.

Moreover, we can define any other loss functions if we can write down the equations. For some training operators (minimizers), the loss function should satisfy some conditions (smooth, differentiable ...).

In one word, Tensorflow define arrays, constants, variables into tensors, define calculations using tf functions, and use session to run though graph. We can define whatever we like and run it in the end.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the other answer, you can write a loss function in Python if it can be represented as a composition of existing functions.

Take a look, for example, at the implementation of `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn.py#L238), which is implemented using basic transformations.

Comment: Maybe this is a more proper [link to existing loss function implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py)

Answer (score 11):

Almost in all tensorflow tutorials they use custom functions. For example in the very [beginning tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started) they write a custom function:

> sums the squares of the deltas between the current model and the provided data

```
squared_deltas = tf.square(linear_model - y)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)
```

In the next [MNIST for beginners they use a cross-entropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners):

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

---

As you see it is not that hard at all: you just need to encode your function in a tensor-format and use their basic functions.

For example here is how **you can implement F-beta score** (a general approach to [F1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score)). Its formula is:

[image]

The only thing we will need to do is to find how to calculate true_positive, false_positive, false_negative for boolean or 0/1 values. If you have vectors of 0/1 values, you can calculate each of the values as:

```
TP = tf.count_nonzero(actual, predicted)
FP = tf.count_nonzero((actual - 1) * predicted)
FN = tf.count_nonzero((predicted - 1) * actual)
```

Now once you know these values you can easily get your

```
denom = (1 + b**2) * TP + b**2 TN + FP
Fb = (1 + b**2) * TP / denom
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your F-beta score implementation suffers multiple issues:
- first line should be: `TP = tf.count_nonzero(actual * predicted)`
- `denom = (1 + b**2) * TP + b**2 FN + FP`
- However, the major problem here is that this implementation can not be used as a custom loss function, because there is no way to calculate the gradients. For example, there is no linear way to determine the `predicted` values.

Comment: One way to solve the gradient problem is to calculate TP, FP and FN by using their predicted probabilities as described by [Scherzinger et al.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-64689-3_29)

Comment: It's also weid because F-beta score is a metric and not a loss, you try to maximize it, not minimize it, so I feel the loss example is not adequate.

Answer (score 7):

```
def focal_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  pt_1 = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 1), y_pred, tf.ones_like(y_pred))
  pt_0 = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 0), y_pred, tf.zeros_like(y_pred))
  custom_loss=kb.square((pt_1-pt_0)/10)
  return custom_loss    

model.compile(loss=focal_loss,
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 5):

My realization of custom loss function with Kullbak-Leibler divergence where p = constant.
I used it in autoencoder.

```
rho = 0.05

class loss_with_KLD(losses.Loss):
    
    def __init__(self, rho):
        super(loss_with_KLD, self).__init__()
        self.rho = rho
        self.kl = losses.KLDivergence()
        self.mse = losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM)
        
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        mse = self.mse(y_true, y_pred)
        kl = self.kl(self.rho, y_pred)
        return mse + kl
```

May be helping to anyone.