# Mean absolute error in TensorFlow without built-in functions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to implement a loss function using mean absolute error without calling the built-in function. Is the code below correct? Because my loss value goes from 28.xx to 0.00028 quickly.

Meanwhile, other loss function like RMSE has a more standard loss curve

```
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(y_pred - Y) / nFeatures)
```

Comment: You should divide by number of examples not number of features (`nFeatures`).

Comment: What is the number of examples? Is it the number of rows?

Comment: Usually it is the first dimension (the batch dimension) of your input tensor. If your input is shaped [batch, num_features], yes it is the number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own lost function base on MAE formula:
[image: img]

```py
import tensorflow as tf
MAE = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(y_true - y_pred))
```

Also you can check customized loss function in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37573411/10452700)

or

```py
import numpy as np
MAE = np.average(np.abs(y_true - y_pred), weights=sample_weight, axis=0)
```

or

```py
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
MAE = math_ops.abs(y_true - y_pred)
```