# How to create a weighted mean absolute error loss function in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a weighted MAE loss function as my data is highly imbalanced. `losses.MeanAbsoluteError` provides an argument `sample_weights`, but only in its `__call__()` function. So I am trying to wrap this function with my own:

```py
def weighted_mean_absolute_error(class_weights):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        weights = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: class_weights.get(t, 1.0), elems=y_true)
        mae = losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
        v = mae(y_true, y_pred, sample_weights=weights)
        return v
    return loss
```

`class_weights` is a dict mapping integers created by a tokenizer to the reciprocal relativ occurrence of the respective integer.

But this function fails at training time, as `y_true` is a symbolic tensor. By training at the latest there should be actuall values.

Is it possible to wrap the function in this way and I am just missing something? Or do I need to implement a weighted mean absolute error myself?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56401346/mean-absolute-error-in-tensorflow-without-built-in-functions/56401550 solve your problem?

Comment: I will try to implement the given solution with the weights and come back later with the results. Thanks

Comment: As I suspected: `y_true` and `y_pred` are symbolic tensors. Therefore the difference between them is also a symbolic tensor. And a symbolic tensor can not be passed to a numpy function. So replace `np.abs()` with `tf.math.abs()` and `np.average()` with `tf.math.reduce_mean()`. I assume the class weights also need to be a tensor and have to be multiplied after applying `tf.math.abs()`. Hopefully this solves my issue.

Comment: I hope, does the link that I've posted solve your issue now? or you still have a problem?

Comment: I did it. You are the best. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @abdou_dev lead me on the right track.
He postet a link to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56401346/mean-absolute-error-in-tensorflow-without-built-in-functions/56401550).
Posted there is following solution for a self made mean absolute error loss funktion:

> ```py
> import numpy as np
> MAE = np.average(np.abs(y_true - y_pred), weights=sample_weight, axis=0)
> ```

However this **DOES NOT** work.

`y_true` and `y_pred` are symbolic tensors and can therefore not be passed to a numpy function. Even the difference is a symbolic tensor and it does not work.

**SOLUTION**

You need to replace `np.abs()` with `tf.math.abs()` and `np.average()` with `tf.math.reduce_mean()`. Those are TensorFlow functions and work with symbolic tensors too. Unfortunately `tf.math.reduce_mean()` does not provide a field for weights. After calculating the absolute value you need to multiply it with the weights. But for this operation the weights need to be a tensor. With a `tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer()` and a `tf.lookup.StaticHashTable()` you can replace the labels with their weights in a copy of `y_true`. Also I needed to cast `y_true` to `tf.float32` as my labels are integers but the model outputs are floats.

The full solution is as following:

```py
def weighted_mean_absolute_error(class_weights):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        init = tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(
            list(class_weights.keys()), list(class_weights.values())
        )
        table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(init, default_value=1.0)
        weights = table.lookup(y_true)
        return tf.math.reduce_mean(
            tf.math.multiply(tf.math.abs(tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32) - y_pred), weights)
        )
    return loss
```

Assumed you have the dict `class_weights` mapping labels to reciprocal relative occurrence of the respective label you use the function like this:

```py
wmae = weighted_mean_absolute_error(class_weights)
# your model definition comes here like:
# model = keras.Sequential()
# model.add(...)
# ...
model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizers.Adam(), # or another optimizer of your choosing
    loss=wmae,
    metrics=[metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()], # or other metrics
)
```

I do not know why Google does not implement a `losses.WeightedMeanAbsoluteError()` themself but this should work.